# Getting req.files as null when trying to upload file using express-fileupload

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to upload a file using express-fileupload. But I am getting req.files as null, but req.body is giving the file information correctly.

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
const app = express();
app.use(fileUpload());
app.post('/upload', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("req files", req.files);
    res.send("Send");
});
```

HTML form

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload">
                    <div class="custom-file">
                        <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile" name="file" required>
                        <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-flex mt-3">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ml-auto">Upload to database</button>
                    </div>
</form>
```

what is wrong in above code?

Comment: Can you check in the network tab  whether file is being sent or not in the request?

Comment: what happens if you try to console `req.files.file`?

Comment: @fedesc it gives `cannot find file of undefined` as error